# remove sanitize_title() for register_taxonomy()

Tags: custom-taxonomy

**Update**
From reading the answers, i think i didn't make myself clear, so i try to post it again.

I register taxonomies from data from parsed xml files. The arguments passed *should* be absolutely correct. What i wanted to know is on which of the arguments of the `register_taxonomy()` function the `sanitize_title()` function get's called. I currently got an error and need to figure out which of the parameters is wrong.

Comment: I don't think register_taxonomy() expects 1st parameter to be  array...

Comment: I know, but somewhere in my parsing process i got an array instead of an string. I need to figure out which part this is. I know that the error get's triggered at the sanitize_title function, so i asked if someone knows which part of the initial data for register_taxonomy runs through sanitize_title.

Comment: It'll help if you can post the code that is failing...

Comment: @MikeSchinkel: It's a lot of code: 3 Classes at all, so i thought maybe someone knows which part of the args array is calling sanitize_title().

Comment: @MikeSchinkel: Please see my answer below (for a proof of my [insert term here]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: **Sorry**, if i wasted your time.

The problem couldn't have been guessed by anyone and was lying in the middle of my class. I simply build an array where i pushed all needed stuff into. This array was rebuilt before i pushed it into the `register_taxonomy()` function. There i simply forgot to unset those parts i didn't need anymore.

@MikeSchinkel @One Trick Pony - please add some answer here, so i can upvote you for your efforts. Thanks to everybody :)

Comment: That's okay, glad you found the answer, nothing really for me to add. Up-vote something else of mine. :)

Answer (score 2):

One Trick Pony is right, register_taxonomy() does not handle arrays.

Comment: Please see update & answer to "One Trick Pony"s comment.